# Trying to print a sring,but getting "@@" in place of data

Tags: c, string, output, printf, gets

I am trying to get a string from the user, then remove all characters in a string, except the alphabets.
The string a string containing whitespace.
I have input a string, but the output is only "@@".

I don't know what's happening.

```
//C program
//Program to remove all characters in a string, except alphabet
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
char str[150], copy[150];
int i = 0, j = 0;
printf("\nEnter a string : ");
fgets(str,150,stdin);
for (i = 0; i < 150; i++)
{
    if ((str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z') || 
    (str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z') || (str[i] == '\0') )
    {
        *(copy + j) == *(str+i);
        j++;
    }
}

printf("\nResultant String : ");
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
{
    printf("%c",copy[i]);
}
printf("\n");
return 0;
}
```

On terminal this is the program being run, I input "1 2 3 4 get on the dance floor".

```
Enter a string : 1 2 3 4 get on the dance floor

Resultant String : @@
```

Comment: Please turn up your compiler warnings. You should get something like this: `*(copy + j) == *(str+i);` `test.c:16:21: warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]`

Comment: Besides the error mentioned above, you could make things much easier and more readable: Use `isalpha(str[i])` (from header `ctype.h`) instead of checking for lower and upper case letter separately. Use array syntax `str[i]` and `copy[j]` instead of explicit pointer arithmetics. You should also stop your loop when you reach the end of the string instead of looping over the whole 150 characters.

Comment: For such small programs you should get used to debugging it. Run it in a debugger step by step and watch how your variables will change. Or in this case, how they will not change as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is you're not doing an assignment here:

```
*(copy + j) == *(str+i);
```

The `==` is for comparison.  You want `=`:

```
*(copy + j) = *(str+i);
```

Your loop conditions are also incorrect:

```
for (i = 0; i < 150; i++)

...

for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
```

For the first loop, you're reading all bytes in the source array instead of just the ones that were set, and in the second one you're using the length of the source string instead of the result string to print the result.  These should be:

```
for (i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)

...

for (int i = 0; i < strlen(copy); i++)
```